# Change element on page init of jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, slider

I try to change slider properties on page init :

```
$(document).delegate('#my-page','pageinit', InitMyPage());

function InitMyPage() {
    var today = new Date();
    $("#my-slider").prop({
        min: 1,
        max: 50
    }).slider("refresh");
}
```

It looks like on the page init `$("#my-slider")` still unknown.

When I try to get it on console at this point its look like this:

```
$("#year-slider")
[]
```

And I get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

When can I change the elements (which event)?

Comment: why not use ``document.ready``???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code:

```
$(document).delegate('#my-page','pageinit', InitMyPage());
```

***calls*** `InitMyPage` and passes its return value into `delegate`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` *calls* `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

To pass the function into `delegate` instead, remove the `()` from after it:

```
$(document).delegate('#my-page','pageinit', InitMyPage);
// No () here ----------------------------------------^
```

> And I get error:
>
> `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`
>
> When can I change the elements (which event)?

That's because `InitMyPage` doesn't return anything, so the result of calling it is `undefined`, which is being passed into `delegate`. Later when the event occurs, apparently jQuery Mobile tries to call that `undefined` (which, not being a function, causes the error). I'm slightly surprised jQuery Mobile doesn't notice that and not try to call it, but... :-) Fixing the other thing will fix this.

Comment: Thank you very much!! that's was the problem :)